# I would like the option not to include education information

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I am nearly 54 and I've been a developer for over 28 years. I have a lot of experience but, while I did graduate high school, I will never earn a degree.

When applying for a position, this is obviously something I would answer truthfully if I'm asked. But this is not something I want to highlight on my resume.

Why not allow users like me to indicate that we do not want to show an education background? I can just choose not to fill it out, but then I'm told I am not unlocking all available features because my profile is not completely filled out.

Comment: So much for posting feedback on this.